# How to pass the span context through the fiber middleware?

Tags: go, open-telemetry, go-fiber

I have the following middleware:

```
testGroup := fiberServer.Group("test")

testGroup.Use(func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    p, span := otel.Tracer("my-service").Start(c.UserContext, "middleware")
    defer span.End()

    /// some work

    return c.Next()
})
```

I want to pass the span `parent` to the next handler. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your parent span is in the same process ( like the function that calls the `testGroup.Use()` ) and the context propagated appropriatly, just passing the context into the `Start()` method handles the nested spans.

If your parent span is in a different process ( like a service that calls your service ), you have to extract and inject the context data, which nowadays is called `propagation` in the [OpenTelemetry specification](https://import%20(%20%20%20%22go.opentelemetry.io/otel%22%20%20%20%22go.opentelemetry.io/otel/propagation%22%20)%20...%20otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.TraceContext%7B%7D)). To do so, you only have to [set the global propagator](https://pkg.go.dev/go.opentelemetry.io/otel#SetTextMapPropagator) one time in your application, like this:

```
import (
  "go.opentelemetry.io/otel"
  "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/propagation"
)
...
otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.TraceContext{})
```

Note that for `gofiber` you also have the option to use the [opentelemetry middleware](https://docs.gofiber.io/contrib/otelfiber_v1.x.x/otelfiber/) called `Otelfiber` and you don't have to propagate it manually in your middleware:

```
otelfiber.Middleware(opts ...otelfiber.Option) fiber.Handler
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as OP. `c.UserContext()` will contain the context object with information about the parent span etc. But if you start a new span, you will get a brand new context that you must pass on to anything that is a child of that span. I don't see any easy way of passing fiber's context down to a child function with the `UserContext()` updated with the new span without then mutating the object.

```golang
testGroup.Use(func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    ctx, span := otel.Tracer("my-service").Start(c.UserContext, "middleware")
    defer span.End()

    /// some work

    // the next middleware will be attached to the root span, not the span we created. This is usually fine, but if we wanted it to be a child of our span, I don't see any way to achieve that.
    return c.Next()
})
```